# How change htaccess Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wpml

I have some error on wordpress site after installing WPML and make some translations, this error make 500 error on my site

```
error: AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer https://mexter.reasavings.top/uk/nakopichuvalni-vodonagrivachi/
```

I found some answers but not now how can i do/change this

my .htaccess has next lines maybe i need change this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
# Директивы (строки) между `BEGIN WordPress` и `END WordPress`
# созданы автоматически и подлежат изменению только через фильтры WordPress.
# Сделанные вручную изменения между этими маркерами будут перезаписаны.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ru/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^uk/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

On wordpress site with WPML has fix in functions.php from theme

need add this lines:

```
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'fix_rewritebase');
function fix_rewritebase($rules){
    $home_root = parse_url(home_url());
    if ( isset( $home_root['path'] ) ) {
        $home_root = trailingslashit($home_root['path']);
    } else {
        $home_root = '/';
    }
 
    $wpml_root = parse_url(get_option('home'));
    if ( isset( $wpml_root['path'] ) ) {
        $wpml_root = trailingslashit($wpml_root['path']);
    } else {
        $wpml_root = '/';
    }
 
    $rules = str_replace("RewriteBase $home_root", "RewriteBase $wpml_root", $rules);
    $rules = str_replace("RewriteRule . $home_root", "RewriteRule . $wpml_root", $rules);
 
    return $rules;
}
```